# LINQ to a class in a group in a list

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I have a

```
List<PublicGrouping<DateTime,Event>>
```

used in a LongListSelector for a windows phone 7 project. PublicGrouping implements IGrouping.

How can I get a List of PublicGrouping where Event.X = Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to find all groups `Where` `Any` of the Events in the group meet a condition:

```
var yGroups = list.Where(g => g.Any(e => e.X == y));
```

**EDIT**:
You're trying to `Select` new groups from the Events in the old Groups `Where` some condition, and you only want non-empty groups:

```
var yGroups = list.Select(g => new PublicGrouping(g.Key, g.Where(e => e.X == y))
                  .Where(g => g.Any());
```

Comment: @karl: Then you need to create new `Grouping` objects with subsets of the Events.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, marked as answer because it works on a regular IGrouping, but unfortunately PublicGrouping (from the wp7 toolkit) only has public PublicGrouping(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> internalGrouping)